Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'indexOf'
here is my code, I rewrote it as in the video tutorial, but it gives an error, please tell me what to do?
before that, an error was shown about the keys, but I checked them
Im sorry? i dont know, what write this, so abcdocdbsdbjsdcjsbd svdcjcb sjdv sjd

const App = () => {
    const [boards, setBoards] = useState ([
        {id: 1, title: "Не начато", items: [{id: 1, title:"a"}, {id:2, title:"b"}, {id:3, title:"c"}] }
    ])

    const [currentBoard, setCurrentBoard] = useState(null)
    const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(null)

    function dOH (e){ e.preventDefault() }
    function dLH (e){}
    function dSH (e, board, item){
        setCurrentBoard(board)
        setCurrentItem(item)
    }
    function dEH (e){}


    function drop(e, board, item) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const currentIndex = currentBoard.item.indexOf(currentItem)
        currentBoard.items.splice(currentIndex, 1)
        const dropIndex = board.items.indexOf(item)
        board.items.splice(dropIndex + 1, 0, currentItem)
        setBoards(boards.map(b => {
            if(b.id === board.id){
                return board
            }
            if(b.id === currentBoard.id){
                return currentBoard
            }
            return b
        }))

    }
    return (
        <div>
            {boards.map (board =>
            <div>
                <div>{board.title}</div>
                {board.items.map (item =>
                    <div 
                    onDragOver={(e) => dOH(e)}
                    onDragLeave={(e) => dLH(e)}
                    onDragStart={(e) => dSH(e, board, item)}
                    onDragEnd={(e) => dEH(e)}
                    onDrop={(e) => drop(e, board, item)}
                    draggable={true}>{item.title} </div>)}
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App```


I tried to rewrite the code as in other tips, but it didn't work out.        


You're are probably trying to access currentBoard while it's value is still null. With the information you provided it's hard to find where the problem is really starting.

There is a typo in the below statement. The property item is incorrect, it is items.
Original code
function drop(e, board, item) {
   ...
   const currentIndex = currentBoard.item.indexOf(currentItem)
   ...
}

Corrected Code
function drop(e, board, item) {
   ...
   const currentIndex = currentBoard.items.indexOf(currentItem)
   ...
}

Test run by fixing the typo
a) On load of the app

b) After the drag and drop of a onto b

c) After the drag and drop of a onto c

